# The right way to use <section> and <article> for SEO

Tags: html, seo

Forgive me if I misspelled it and please correct it.

I do not know exactly how to use these two elements (`Article` | `Section`)
Now I want to launch a site that has completely standard HTML code,
Now, how do you think an article from my site should be structured? And where can I put the site header better?
I am stuck between these two options.

```
<!-- 1 -->
<section>
    <header>
        <h1>title of page</h1>
    </header>
    <article>
        <p>some text</p>
    </article>
</section>

<!-- 2 -->
<section>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>title of page</h1>
        </header>
    </article>
    <p>some text</p>
</section>
```

If both are incorrect, what do you suggest?

My English is very poor. So I could not use any more questions. But I understand the coding. Please explain to me by writing the code and simple sentences, and do not say that there is an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about the **[HTML element `article`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article)** of Mozilla:

> The  HTML element represents a self-contained composition in
> a document, page, application, or site, which is intended to be
> independently distributable or reusable (e.g., in syndication)... each
> post would be contained in an  element, possibly with one or
> more s within.

Unlike the `article` element, the **[`section` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)**:

> The  HTML element represents a generic standalone section of
> a document, which **doesn't have a more specific semantic element** to
> represent it.

Thus, the article element can contain section elements. But the `section` element cannot contain any other semantic elements.

Accordingly, your example can be presented like this:

```html
<header>
 <h1>The article News from Valinor of Gandalf</h1>
</header>
<article>
  <h2>News from Valinor</h2>
  <p>A short introduction to the content of the article.</p>
  <section>
    <h3>The name of section</h3>
    <p>The content of section.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>The name of section</h3>
    <p>The content of section.</p>
  </section>
  ...
</article>
<footer>
 <h2>Publisher and copyright holder</h2>
 <p>Publisher and © 2021 Gandalf</p>
</footer>
```